# mysqli_fetch_array() - error when I add another column to match

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a little search engine application in PHP, and I get stuck at ranking websites. In a code I have a simple query, which should match the user query (input) against description of website.

```
$row2 = [];
$search_word = false;
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    //edit this with your credentials
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "uThx6wuf", "search");

    if(mysqli_connect_error()) echo "Connection Fail";
    else {
        $search_word = true;
        $input = $_POST["s_input"];

        // tokenize input
        $tokens = tokenize($input);

        //compute weight of every token
        $token_weight = compute_weight($tokens, $con);

        $sql2 = "SELECT *, match(description) against('". $input ."') as score FROM search where match(description) against('".$input."') order by score desc";

        $result2 = mysqli_query($con, $sql2);

        $sql3 = "SELECT * FROM search";
        $numDocs = (mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($con, $sql3)));

        $maxOverlap = sizeof($tokens);
        $ctr2 = 0;
        while($ctr2 != $maxOverlap){
            //compute inverse_document_frequency of term
            $sql3 = "SELECT *, match(description) against('".$tokens[$ctr2]."') FROM search where match(description) against('".$tokens[$ctr2]."')";
            $docFreq = (mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($con, $sql3)));
            $idf[$tokens[$ctr2]] = idf($numDocs, $docFreq);
            $ctr2++;
        }
```

When I add another column to match, everytime I get an error

```
mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in
```

Code of edited query:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT *, match(description, title) against('". $input ."') as score FROM search where match(description, title) against('".$input."') order by score desc";
```

Comment: Please try to paste that error in the search box. It is asked literally dozens of times already.

Comment: There's just one error - I have it pasted in the question.

Answer (score 0):

first of all run the query in your sql browser first with an existing information in the database if the query is ok

check the inputs been received if its ok too

it seems your error is from the sql syntax or the input been fed to the sql syntax.

Comment: I can run old query without problems (sql browser, php), but once I add another column in match (title), it gives me the error - in sql browser it's #1191 - Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list .